# warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: const_declaration [-Wother]

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc

I have the following `yacc` grammar:

```
%{
#include  <stdio.h>
extern FILE* yyin;
extern char* yytext;

%}

%token VAR ID_NAME TYPE_STRING TYPE_BOOL TYPE_NUMBER CONST

%%

var_declaration: VAR ':' type ID_NAME ';' { printf("var\n"); }
    ;

const_declaration: CONST ':' type ID_NAME ';' {printf("const\n");}
    ;

type: TYPE_NUMBER
    | TYPE_STRING
    | TYPE_BOOL
    ;

%%
void yyerror (char const *s) {
    fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{

    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

It should describe a little language that at this time should allow variable declarations of the form `var:<type> <name>;` and constants declarations of the form `const:<type> <name>;`.

When I run `yacc -vd grammar.y` I get:
yacc -vd grammar.y

```
grammar.y: warning: 1 nonterminal useless in grammar [-Wother]
grammar.y: warning: 1 rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
grammar.y:16.1-17: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: const_declaration [-Wother]
 const_declaration: CONST ':' type ID_NAME ';' {printf("const\n");}
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grammar.y:16.20-67: warning: rule useless in grammar [-Wother]
 const_declaration: CONST ':' type ID_NAME ';' {printf("const\n");}
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why does it say that `const_declaration` rule is useless?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you get this error message is that the rule `const_declaration` does not appear in any other rule, and is thus not needed for the grammar.

The rule `var_declaration` is taken as the **start** rule (as you have not specified a start it uses the first one). This rule only uses the `type` rule and thus all other rules are redundant, which is what it is telling you.

Perhaps this is a subset of a larger grammar? When all the grammar is in the file and the `const_declaration` rule is used somewhere the error will go away.

Comment: You are right. Both rules for variables and constants are components of a (not yet defined) program rule.